# "Unknown Entity namespace alias" exception

Tags: php, exception, orm, symfony-3.3

I'm experiencing troubles with my new bundle, AdminBundle, I've just created. I see the following ORMException message:

> Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AdminBundle'.

This is the *DefaultController.php*:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/dashboard", name="admin_default_dashboard")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function dashboardAction()
    {

        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rObject = $manager->getRepository('AdminBundle:Object');

        return $this->render('AdminBundle:Default:dashboard.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is the doctrine configuration in my *config.yml* file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

And this is *ObjectRepository.php* file:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\Object;

class ObjectRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

I've tried to check out solutions from similar threads but none of them worked to me.

**edit:**

This is the Object entity code: http://collabedit.com/agyh8

PS. Thanks, Arkovsky, for your advice. I'm going to change the entity name for sure.

Comment: Can you show your entity class? BTW. Using Object as entity name is not a good practice.

Comment: Please check out my edit of the post.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you made a bundle without a vendor name, and that's probably why it's bugging.
When you create a bundle in Symfony use this console command in your symfony project :

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

Then they ask you a name for your bundle. Here you got to write something with this pattern :  Bob\AdminBundle
(You can change "Bob" by whatever vendor name you like). Then follow the instructions and it should work fine.
From now, the entire name of your bundle that you are going to use in your controller is going to be : "BobAdminBundle".
Example :

```
return $this->render('BobAdminBundle:Default:dashboard.html.twig');
```

Comment: I did not created the vendor name because I didn't supposed to share my bundle between other people. It is worth adding that only `$rObject = $manager->getRepository('AdminBundle:Object');` line causes the problem. The rest of the action is good.

Comment: Ok, thanks for claryfing. Can you show us the code of src/AdminBundle/Entity/Object.php please ?

Comment: There is no such as file as I'm going to share the AppBundle/Entity/Object entity between two bundles.

Comment: Alright, then the issue comes from the fact that your entity, and so, the repository associated, belongs to Appbundle and not AdminBundle

Comment: Perhaps :) Could you show me the way to correctly achieve this goal?

Comment: On top of your controller, add the code : "use AppBundle\Entity\Object;"

and then edit your line that returns the error like this :
$rObject = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:Object');

Comment: It is not the solution because AdminBundle has his own Repository and what you propose is to use the AppBundle's Repository.

Comment: Yes, but your Object entity belongs to AppBundle. In this case you got to call the repository from AppBundle.
If you want to call your AdminBundle repository, you got to create your entity in AdminBundle

Comment: I'm sure that there is some way to use ONE entity by a few bundles in Symfony.